# Python output overlaps

Tags: python

I have written a script to calculate the response time for accessing a website. Below is the print statement in my script:

```
print "OK: Completed in %s %s|time=%s"%(delta, host, seconds)
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.py
|time=3.693447in 0:00:03.693447 HIT from 127.0.0.1
```

As you can see time variable is getting print infront of the line as my output is overlapping.

Can someone help me to identify what I am doing wrong in `print` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `\r` carriage return in the `host` variable (as the last character). This sends the cursor back to the start of the line, causing the remainder of the string (`|time=....`) to overwrite whatever came before.

You can use the [`str.strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to clear it from the variable:

```
print "OK: Completed in %s %s|time=%s" % (delta, host.strip(), seconds)
```

The `str.strip()` method removes *all* whitespace from the start and end of a string (returning a new string object); whitespace is defined as tabs, spaces, newlines and carriage returns.

Demo:

```
>>> delta = '0:00:03.693447'  # a string will do for the demo
>>> seconds = 3.693447
>>> host = 'foobar\r'
>>> print "OK: Completed in %s %s|time=%s"%(delta, host, seconds)
|time=3.693447in 0:00:03.693447 foobar
>>> print "OK: Completed in %s %s|time=%s" % (delta, host.strip(), seconds)
OK: Completed in 0:00:03.693447 foobar|time=3.693447
```